# React hooks and functional component ref

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

```
const Comp1 = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    print: () => {
      console.log('comp1')
    }
  }), []);
  return <div>comp1</div>
});

const Comp2 = () => <div>comp2</div>;

const App = () => {
  const ref1 = useRef(null);
  const ref2 = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref1); // prints ref1 with the expected current  
    console.log(ref2); // prints ref2 with current: null
  })
  return <div><Comp1 ref={ref1}/><Comp2 ref={ref2}/></div>
}
```

1. What's the difference between Comp1 and Comp2 refs?
2. Why do I have to use forwardRef along with useImperativeHandle in order to actually get the ref to Comp1?

https://codepen.io/benma/pen/mddEWjP?editors=1112

Comment: here is a good thread about the topic: https://twitter.com/acemarke/status/1182466648646832129

Comment: @LefiTarik Thanks! I was actually looking for some info about this hook and couldn't find much,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React documentation says:

> You may not use the ref attribute on function components because they don’t have instances. ([more](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs))

This means that you can't bind your refs to functional components. That's why your `ref2.current` is `null`. If you want to bind ref to component, you need to use class components. Your `ref1` is not a ref to the `Comp1` component. It actually contains an object that you passed in `useImperativeHandle` hook. i.e. it contains the next object:

```
{
    print: () => {
      console.log('comp1')
    }
}
```

You have to use `forwardRef` with functional components if you want to bind your ref with some HTML element or class component that your component renders. Or you could bind your ref with some object with using of `useImperativeHandle` hook.

**UPDATE**

The using of `useImperativeHandle` is the same as adding methods to your class component:

```
class Comp1 extends React.Component {
    print() {
        console.log('comp1');
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>comp1</div>)
    }
}
```

is the same as

```
const Comp1 = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    print: () => {
      console.log('comp1')
    }
  }), []);
  return <div>comp1</div>
});
```

*You asked in a comment:*

> So after moving to hooks (and still avoid using classes), the only way to use ref is to use `useImperativeHandle` (and actually use a "fake" ref)? Is this a good practice?

*Answer:* Using of `useImperativeHandle` is the same bad practice as calling child component methods by refs in class components. React doc says that you should avoid calling child component methods by refs, you should avoid using of `useImperativeHandle`. Also, you need to avoid using refs where you can do things without them.

Comment: So after moving to hooks (and still avoid using classes), the only way to use ref is to use useImperativeHandle (and actually use a "fake" ref)? Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. What's the difference between Comp1 and Comp2 refs?

`Comp1` uses `React.forwardRef` and will be able to receive a given `ref` from parent.
`Comp2` won't work and trigger following error:

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use `React.forwardRef()`?

`<Child ref={ref1}/>` is like a request from parent component: "Hey `Child`, please pass your component reference or similar into given mutable store box (`ref`), so I can invoke a method on you or manipulate a contained DOM node directly."

Problem - there is no *instance* for function components:

```
// React internally calls `new ClassComp()`, instance can be stored and passed in a ref
<ClassComp ref={compRef} />

// React just *calls* the function for re-renders, there is no plain function "instance" 
<FunctionComp ref={compRef} />
```

[`React.forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) solves above limitation. With

```
const FunctionComp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Hello FnComp</div>
```

, `FunctionComp`  can still pass something representative to the `ref` given from `Parent` (like `div` DOM node), despite having no instance. `ClassComp` instead passes its instance here.

---

> 2. Why do I have to use `forwardRef` along with `useImperativeHandle` in order to actually get the ref to `Comp1`?

You don't have to. `useImperativeHandle` is an extension to provide a more custom imperative call API. Following three alternatives are equivalent:

`forwardRef` only:

```js
const App = () => {
  const compRef = React.useRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <Comp ref={compRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          compRef.current.focus();
        }}
      >
        Focus input
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const Comp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  return <input ref={ref} />;
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

`useImperativeHandle` only, with custom ref prop (take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578570/value-of-using-react-forwardref-vs-custom-ref-prop/60237948#60237948) for more info):

```js
const App = () => {
  const compRef = React.useRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <Comp customRef={compRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          compRef.current.focus();
        }}
      >
        Focus input
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const Comp = ({ customRef }) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  React.useImperativeHandle(customRef, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

`useImperativeHandle` + `forwardRef`:

```js
const App = () => {
  const compRef = React.useRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <Comp ref={compRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          compRef.current.focus();
        }}
      >
        Focus input
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const Comp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} />;
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer from question 2

- useImperativeHandle described that the reference call syntax will be with 
  some customized methods of the instance value that is exposed to parent.
- forwardRef  helps  forward a ref through a Higher-order component to reference an inner DOM node.

when you  will try to focus:  ref1.current.focus(), the child input will be focused and not higher order component that wrapping the child input.

Look at simple example related to answer with setValue method of useImperativeHandle and forward input in ChildInput:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-useimperativehandle-huktt

Comment: just to highlight: it has been working before hooks arrived. So `forwareRef((prop, ref) => { .... ref.current = {setValue: (value) => ....} )` works as well. `useImperativeHandle` just encapsulate working with references and make some additional checks, say, in case callback-type reference.