# value of using React.forwardRef vs custom ref prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I see that `React.forwardRef` seems to be the sanctioned way of passing a ref to a child functional component, from the react docs:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

However, what is the advantage of doing this over simply passing a custom prop?:

```
const FancyButton = ({ innerRef }) => (
  <button ref={innerRef} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton innerRef={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

The only advantage I can think of is maybe having a consistent api for refs, but is there any other advantage? Does passing a custom prop affect diffing when it comes to rendering and cause additional renders, surely not as the ref is stored as mutable state in the `current` field?

Say for example you wanted to pass multiple refs (which tbh, might indicate code smell, but still), then the only solution I can see would be to use customRef props.

I guess my question is what is the value of using `forwardRef` over a custom prop?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Even [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components) mention the custom ref prop as a more flexible approach to `forwardRef`:

> If you use React 16.2 or lower, or if you need **more flexibility than provided by ref forwarding**, you can use this alternative approach and explicitly pass a **ref as a differently named prop**.

There is also a [gist](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1a018a023347fe1c2476073330cc5509), in which Dan Abramov writes about its advantages:

- compatible with all React versions
- works for class and function components
- simplifies passing a ref to a nested component several layers deep

I would add, that passing refs as usual props does not cause [breaking changes](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#note-for-component-library-maintainers) and is the way to go for multiple refs. The only advantages of `forwardRef` coming to my mind are:

- uniform access API for DOM nodes, functional and class components (you mentioned that)
- `ref` attribute does not bloat your props API, e.g. if you provide types with TypeScript

> Does passing a custom prop affect diffing when it comes to rendering and cause additional renders?

A ref can potentially trigger a re-render if you pass an inline [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) function down as prop. But it is a [better idea](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats-with-callback-refs) anyway to define it as class instance method or via some memoization like `useCallback`.

Comment: Awesome thanks Ford, I kind of thought that might be the case was just keen to shine some light on it.

Comment: the advantage points are't quite big enough reason to introduce an entire API, just code bloat imho

Comment: This is bonkers. Function Components ignore the `ref` prop (does not pass it as prop, and sets `current = null`.   
So, it seems forwardRef() has no justification except to encourage black boxing of components.

Comment: the major disadvantage of `React.forwardRef` is that you lose type checking with regards to the `Props` of a component. At least I haven't discovered how to use `forwardRef` and keep type checking for passed properties.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Is this what you're looking for?
`ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<PutComponentPropsHere> & RefAttributes<PutComponentForRefHere>>`

Comment: This doesn't really answer why you _would_ use forwardRef over the prop approach, therefore it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 1):

If you want a level of abstraction in ChildComponent, forwards Refs can be use in addition with useImperativeHandle hook only to expose specific methods of ref

eg:

```
 useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      focus() {
        inputRef.current.focus();
      },
      scrollIntoView() {
        inputRef.current.scrollIntoView();
      },
    };
  }, []);
```

here parent component can only access focus and scrollIntoView methods