# What are the benefits of using forwardRef instead of passing the ref as custom prop to child components in React?

Tags: reactjs

Are there some benefits in using `forwardRef` over `custom prop` approach? One assumption that comes to a mind is that with forwardRef React won't try to serialize the passed element, but I'm pretty sure it will not serialize it in both cases. Am I right or wrong?

**Custom prop approach**:

```
import { useRef } from "react";

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const someRef = useRef(document.createElement("div"));

  return <ChildComponent somePropWithRef={someRef}/>;
}

const ChildComponent = ({somePropWithRef}) => {
  return <div>Ref is {somePropWithRef.current.nodeName}</div>
}

export default ParentComponent
```

**Same with forwardRef**:

```
import { useRef, forwardRef } from "react";

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const someRef = useRef(document.createElement("div"));

  return <ChildComponent ref={someRef}/>;
}

const ChildComponent = forwardRef((_, ref) => {
  return <div>Ref is {ref.current.nodeName}</div>
});

export default ParentComponent
```

Bonus question: will custom prop approach somehow affect the behavior of **useImperativeHandle** hook?

Comment: Pretty sure https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html explains this already?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578570/value-of-using-react-forwardref-vs-custom-ref-prop