Why refs are not regular Props?
I saw news that refs could be accessed through props in functional components in React 19, but before that, why couldn't refs be accessed from regular props? I wonder why!
I studied about refs, but I couldn't find a reason why refs can't be accessed with regular props. I simply saw that refs and props are separated, but I want to know why they are separated like this in React.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578570/value-of-using-react-forwardref-vs-custom-ref-prop/78947274#78947274?

If you need to use the ref value as prop in a child componet look at forwardRef
